# Why does model look great and detailed in Daz but when I import it to Blender it looks bad?

Tags: texturing, materials, import

So in Daz the model looks greatly detailed with a glossy and metallic finish but when I import it to blender the quality looks awful and the metallic finish is completely gone and replaced with a matte white finish and the shine/gloss is not there either. I attached two pictures, one from Daz and one from blender in rendered view. Please tell me how I can fix this because I have tried almost everything to my ability/knowledge but haven’t found a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Daz:

[image: Daz]

Blender:

[image: Blender]

Comment: They are different shading system, dataA will be translate to dataB, even when you import something from C4D into blender,the problem is the same.The only way is rebuild your material.

Comment: lighting and materials but mostly lighting.  The Daz scene has lighting that adds apparent detail to the scene. The Blender scene does not.

Comment: please post screenshots, rather than photos of scenes.

Comment: Did you export using the fbx export or did you use the DazToBlender bridge?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

notice the reflections on the daz scene.  They are likely using an hdri in Daz.  In the screenshots below I am using eevee whereas I think you are using cycles but the concept is the same.

Edit:
Secondly you need to make the actual materials more reflective.  This can be done in the shader editor.  you can do this by adding a glossy shader on to a diffuse shader. adding glossy:
[image]
in this first image I have a metalic looking sphere in render preview using the blender default forest.exr hdri.
[image: image in render preview with hdri]

this is that same sphere in rendered mode with only a point light above it.
[image: image in render mode]
to add an hdri you need to go to the shader editor and switch from object to world
[image: switching from object to world in shader editor]
you also need to add the hdri as an environment texture.  use shift+a to add a node
[image: adding an environment texture]
final result:
[image: final result of adding a hdri]

Comment: Thank you so much Hunter and everyone else for the comments. I would give you an upvote but I just started out here and don’t have enough reputation.